# WEBKIT: The following environment variables were not found: 1>$(PRODUCTION)

Tags: webkit

I had a problem in building Webkit.
I am pasting the same here.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WinLauncher, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'WinLauncher', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Performing Pre-Build Event...
1>/usr/bin/bash
**1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 1 returned from 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe'.
1>Project : warning PRJ0018 : The following environment variables were not found:
1>$(PRODUCTION)**
1>Build log was saved at "file://D:\Webkit_build\DOLFIN\SHP\ShpBrowser\Dolfin\Engine\webkit\WebKitBuild\obj\WinLauncher\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>WinLauncher - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help me solve the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not important.
I had similar problems recently and solved it however I don't remember how but you can check the following resource, it may help: 
http://siphon9.net/loune/2009/07/compiling-webkitcairo-on-windows-with-visual-c-express/